# Software to fill out PDF via PHP

Tags: pdf, php, pdf-generation

I am in need of a Software to be able to fill out a interactive via PHP.

After my research I came across "pdftk" and similar tools. Sadly I have no possibility to install these on my shared hoster (united-domains).
I have also found "SetaPDF-FormFiller" which seems to be able to fulfill my needs but when comparing Open-Source to a 1200€ licenses Software I would rather go with a free Open-Source Solution.

Does anyone know a good alternative to pdftk where I can just download the package and include it without having to have root access to the server?

Comment: Did you able to find any alternate to PDFTK ever? i have same requirement and we cannot use PDFTK on new servers.

Comment: @SharadGoel Sadly not